# parsing address "label" fields in Excel, C#, VBA, other?

Tags: c#, parsing, street-address

Someone's sent me a Word file full off address labels separated by tabs. See [image: this sample]

I'm trying to figure out the best way to import the addresses into individual records. Probably just go with NameLine, Address1, Address2 for each one (3 fields that I can parse later).

What can I do easily with C# or VBA? Or UltraEdit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Excel for things like this. Just copy the text from Word, paste it into Excel, and use the text import wizard with a tab delimiter, making sure to treat consecutive delimiters as one.

Excel can even parse it for you:

1. Cut and paste the columns so that it's just one long column with all the addresses. (Let's say column A)
2. Assuming each address record is 3 lines long, we want to get that into a format with three columns: Name, Address1, Address2.
3. In Cell `B1`, create formula `=A1`.
4. In Cell `C1`, create formula `=A2`.
5. In Cell `D1`, create formula `=A3`.
6. Select cells `B1` through `D3`, or `D4` if you have blank lines between each address record.
7. Copy.
8. Go to cell `B4`, or `B5` if there's blank lines between each address record.
9. `CTRL+END` to select everything until the end of the data (basically, cells `B5:DXX` should be selected)
10. Paste.
11. Create a new record at the top with your desired fields names.

Example result:
[image: example result image]

Afterwards, you can copy the results into a new worksheet (sans formulae, so it'll just be static text), format the data however you want it, and sort the data to remove those pesky blank lines.

Answer (score 1):

If all the tabs line up in Word, you should be able to `Alt-Select` to select individual columns, then cut & paste them into one sequential column so you just get one contiguous file of `Address1,Address2,Address3,BlankLine`, which should then be trivial to parse.

Comment: +1 I didn't know about `Alt-Select` in Word. That's a neat trick.